# How to get the value inside the if condition?

Tags: android

I am comparing strings in if condition and printing the value of selectedradbtn inside the if condition. Here the **selectedradbtn** is printing inside the if condition...but when I am printing before if condition the value is printing...

My code:

```
 ArrayList<String> array2;
static int selectedradbtn;


selectedradbtn = Previouspage.selectedradiobtn;
System.out.println("selected radio button outside if"+selectedradbtn); //here value is printing
if(Integer.toString(selectedradbtn).equals(array2.get(0)) && array2.get(3).equals("1") )
{
   System.out.println("selected radio button in if"+selectedradbtn); //value not printing
   correct = correct+ 1;
   System.out.println("correct if"+correct);
}
```

Where I am going wrong...please help me regarding this...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Maybe you don't enter in in the `if` block because the conditions are `false`?

Comment: Just debugged your code whether execution enters in if block or not..

Comment: is your arraylist empty?????or please check 'if' conditions before if block in Log or in System.out.println

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but does this help

```
    selectedradbtn = Previouspage.selectedradiobtn;
System.out.println("selected radio button outside if"+selectedradbtn); //here value is          printing
 if((Integer.toString(selectedradbtn).equals(array2.get(0)) && (array2.get(3).equals("1")))
{
  System.out.println("selected radio button in if"+selectedradbtn); //value not printing
  correct = correct+ 1;
  System.out.println("correct if"+correct);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an else {} and check if your condition is satisfied or not.